# function argument passing pointer mess

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I need to pass this data to a function, but can't figure out the correct syntax for the receiving function.

Example code

```
NPOI_SCAN_HEADER *h;

int iBline;
int baselineId;
for (iBline = 0; iBline < h->iNumBlines; iBline++)
{
    baselineId = addBaseline(h->pBase[iBline]);
}

int addBaseline(BASELINE *b)
{
    ...
}
```

"NPOI_SCAN_HEADER" is a struct that contains "BASELINE *pBase".

"BASELINE" is a struct and within it is the data that addBaseline() needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `pBase` is a `BASELINE *`, `pBase[iBline]` is going to be a `BASELINE`. So to get a `BASELINE *`, you need to take its address:

```
baselineId=addBaseline(&(h->pBase[iBline]));
```

Or just add the offset:

```
baselineId=addBaseline(h->pBase + iBline);
```